# Часть описания метки в всплывающем сообщении - на английском

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, метки

Если пользователь не только отвечал на вопросы с какой-либо меткой, но и задавал их, то при наведении на эту метку возникает не полностью переведенное на русский язык сообщение. Вот примерно такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понятно, почему изменился хеш строк. Вернул на место старый вариант. Будет на сайте после выполнения независящих от меня действий.