# Awarded N times на странице описания знака

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, знаки

Например здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/116/c

> Awarded 22 times

Наверное по той же самой неясной причине, что и [соседний дефект](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6712/203622) с описанием меток.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перевод уже исправлен, но обновления базы Transifex ещё не попали в сборку. Как только это произойдёт - всё появится на сайте. Надеюсь, что сегодня. Иначе придётся ждать понедельника, на выходных новых сборок обычно не бывает.

P.S. на [странице знаков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) "awarded" это обновление тоже коснётся. Только лишь вчера разработчик пофиксил дефект: [Unable to pluralize "awarded" on the badges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305581/339911). Поэтому надо немного подождать :)